# react-pdf Image CORS issue

Tags: reactjs, pdf, cors, react-pdf

Can someone please help me / direct me in the right direction.

I am using react-pdf to generate a pdf report which contains images. I am using the Image component from react-pdf to generate a preview of the image. However, I am having a CORS issue only when using react-pdf. I am able to view the images from my react app as a preview using a HTML img tag with the image url. I am storing the images on firebase storage.

The error is

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file-location-here' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What I have done so far

- Added cors with gsutil, and then running gsutil cors get firebase-gs-link returns [{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET"], "origin": ["*"]}]
- Checking the dev console Network tab the Header response does not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin field. I think this is the issue. Not sure why this is happening though.
- This is how I am trying to generate the image

```
    const options = {
        httpHeaders: { 'crossOrigin': 'anonymous' },
      };

    <Image key={imageIndex} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} options={options} src={{ uri: `${file.url}`, method: "GET", headers: { Pragma: 'no-cache', "Cache-Control": "no-cache" }, body: "" }} />
```

I have read all other support tickets from github and stackoverflow and followed the instructions to try and rectify the CORS issue that only occurs with react-pdf. As I said, the file is accessible from my react app, and clicking the link does open the file in a new browser window.